# Highlight Text in Userform TextBox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I want to select/highlight all text in a TextBox on my Userform. I already found >20 forums with the .SelStart and .SelLength solution but it is not working for me...

Are there settings or properties that I need to change to be able to use this?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub MaterialDescriptionTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Len(MaterialDescriptionTextBox.Value) > 40 Then
    MsgBox "The material description can not exceed 40 characters", vbInformation, "Too many characters"
    With Me.MaterialDescriptionTextBox
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
End If
```

Sadly it does not do anything asside from displaying the MsgBox.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `Cancel = True`. The Cancel cancels the `Exit` event itself but any other code after that will still run.

```
Private Sub MaterialDescriptionTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Len(MaterialDescriptionTextBox.Value) > 40 Then
        MsgBox "The material description can not exceed 40 characters", vbInformation, "Too many characters"
        Cancel = True
        With MaterialDescriptionTextBox
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One follow-up: if I add a text of more than 40 characters and then decide to click Cancel (code: Unload Me), this will not work because it will go to the Exit event. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Nicolas I don't understand this parth `click Cancel (code: Unload Me),` How would you click a cancel and how does it relate to Unload Me?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I have another sub: CancelButton_Click() which runs "Unload Me" to close the userform. However I cannot click this when I am in the MaterialDescriptionTextBox and there are over 40 characters because exitting this textbox wil trigger my initial sub and will cancel the CancelButton_Click sub.

Comment: @Nicolas that's a wrong approach. The Cancel button should use `Me.Hide` and unloading should be taking place in a standard module like `UserForm1.Show` and when you finally clicked the `Cancel` button an a userform the control returns to the code and then you call `Unload UserForm1`. Technically you are still in the Userform when you try to Unload it and this is discouraged. See [**THIS**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/two-column-listbox-userform-and-saving-results-to-spreadsheet/) to get an idea

Comment: This does not solve my issue though. Is there a way to ignore the Exit event only if I click the Cancel button?

Comment: @Nicolas not sure what you mean. Can you ask a new question instead?

Answer (score 0):

form userform properties make the show modal = false